# Stumped in Volkrund Keep

Tags: the-elder-scrolls-v-skyrim, skyrim-falskaar

In Volkrund Keep I got the door open. We went down the hall and turned left down some stairs. Here is the problem: the room at the bottom has furniture all over, some floating in air. It was strange, but ok, I thought. Down another hall with cells on either side. I turn right and there is another large room with spider web guarding it so you cannot get thru. How to get thru and does anyone else have this problem?

Comment: What is the full quest name for this?

Answer (score 2):

These areas are easily accessed when following Brother Arnand from  Bailun Priory during his quest "Dreams in Oblivion".

Comment: Brother Armand is at the priory and he will not even talk to me, much less go to Voolkrund